# How to do masking using angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, masking

Is it possible to create a mask in Angular 5 that looks like this:

`XXX-XX-1234`

And when the user clicks on the text box it should change to the following text:

`1234121234`

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes there are plugins like NGMask to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a mask would do the trick. You could also use a pipe, so that you don't actually change the value, just mask it. Here's a simple example I put together for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmlij?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.componenthtml

Comment: Might I suggest putting the code that is needed for the implementation in the answer instead of on a separate website? :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in your code what ever the value i enter its masking the whole thing but mask should show the last 4 digits from the value i enter!! Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @DavidWalschots thanks man. I tried my requirement and did the following https://stackblitz.com/edit/onblurr

Answer (score 0):

you can add a regex to change it.

```
value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/);
```

it will return 4 arrays and you can concatenate them as you wish, for example

```
!x[2] ? x[1] : `${x[1]}-${x[2]}${x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : ''}`;
```